# Get a unique ID for worker in python multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is there a way to assign each worker in a python multiprocessing pool a unique ID in a way that a job being run by a particular worker in the pool could know which worker is running it? According to the docs, a `Process` has a `name` but

> The name is a string used for identification purposes only. It has no
>   semantics. Multiple processes may be given the same name.

For my particular use-case, I want to run a bunch of jobs on a group of four GPUs, and need to set the device number for the GPU that the job should run on. Because the jobs are of non-uniform length, I want to be sure that I don't have a collision on a GPU of a job trying to run on it before the previous one completes (so this precludes pre-assigning an ID to the unit of work ahead of time).

Comment: Why not use something random like uuid ?

Comment: @LuperRouch - Could you expand on what you mean by that?

Comment: For example ``process = Process(target=foo, name=uuid.uuid4().hex)`` would give unique names to your processes.

Comment: Note that getting a unique ID for workers and a unique ID for jobs are different things. Readers who really want a unique ID for jobs instead can just do `p.map(f, enumerate(jobs))`, change `f`'s signature to `f(arg)`, and unpack `i, x = arg` as first line of `f`.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It seems like what you want is simple: `multiprocessing.current_process()`. For example:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(x):
    print multiprocessing.current_process()
    return x * x

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
print p.map(f, range(6))
```

Output:

```
$ python foo.py 
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

This returns the process object itself, so the process can be its own identity. You could also call `id` on it for a unique numerical id -- in cpython, this is the memory address of the process object, so I don't *think* there's any possibility of overlap. Finally, you can use the `ident` or the `pid` property of the process -- but that's only set once the process is started.

Furthermore, looking over the source, it seems to me very likely that autogenerated names (as exemplified by the first value in the `Process` repr strings above) are unique. `multiprocessing` maintains an `itertools.counter` object for every process, which is used to generate an [`_identity`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ed954d11dadd/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#l98) tuple for any child processes it spawns. So the top-level process produces child process with single-value ids, and they spawn process with two-value ids, and so on. Then, if no name is passed to the `Process` constructor, it simply [autogenerates the name](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ed954d11dadd/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#l111) based on the _identity, using `':'.join(...)`. Then `Pool` [alters the name](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ed954d11dadd/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l223) of the process using `replace`, leaving the autogenerated id the same.

The upshot of all this is that although two `Process`es *may* have the same name, because you *may* assign the same name to them when you create them, they are unique if you don't touch the name parameter. Also, you could theoretically use `_identity` as a unique identifier; but I gather they made that variable private for a reason!

An example of the above in action:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(x):
    created = multiprocessing.Process()
    current = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print 'running:', current.name, current._identity
    print 'created:', created.name, created._identity
    return x * x

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
print p.map(f, range(6))
```

Output:

```
$ python foo.py 
running: PoolWorker-1 (1,)
created: Process-1:1 (1, 1)
running: PoolWorker-2 (2,)
created: Process-2:1 (2, 1)
running: PoolWorker-3 (3,)
created: Process-3:1 (3, 1)
running: PoolWorker-1 (1,)
created: Process-1:2 (1, 2)
running: PoolWorker-2 (2,)
created: Process-2:2 (2, 2)
running: PoolWorker-4 (4,)
created: Process-4:1 (4, 1)
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: The `id` attribute doesn't seem to exist anymore, but `pid` and `ident` do (and they are identical; `pid` is just an alias for `ident`).

Answer (score 8):

You can use `multiprocessing.Queue` to store the ids and then get the id at initialization of the pool process.

Advantages:

- You do not need to rely on internals.
- If your use case is to manage resources/ devices then you can put in the device number directly. This will also ensure that no device is used twice: If you have more processes in your pool than devices, the additional processes will block on `queue.get()` and will not perform any work (This won't block your porgram, or at least it did not when I tested).

Disadvantages:

- You have additional communication overhead and spawning the pool
  processes takes a tiny bit longer: Without the `sleep(1)` in the
  example all work might be performed by the first process, as others
  are not done initializing, yet.
- You need a global (or at least I
  don't know a way around it)

Example:

```
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

def init(queue):
    global idx
    idx = queue.get()

def f(x):
    global idx
    process = multiprocessing.current_process()
    sleep(1)
    return (idx, process.pid, x * x)

ids = [0, 1, 2, 3]
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
idQueue = manager.Queue()

for i in ids:
    idQueue.put(i)

p = multiprocessing.Pool(8, init, (idQueue,))
print(p.map(f, range(8)))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 8289, 0), (1, 8290, 1), (2, 8294, 4), (3, 8291, 9), (0, 8289, 16), (1, 8290, 25), (2, 8294, 36), (3, 8291, 49)]
```

Note, that there are only 4 different pid, although the pool contains 8 processes and one idx is only used by one process.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with threading and ended up using [a queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#queue-objects) to handle job management.  Here is the baseline.  My complete version has a bunch of `try-catches` (particularly in the worker, to make sure that `q.task_done()` is called even on failure).

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time
import random


def run(idx, *args):
    time.sleep(random.random() * 1)
    print idx, ':', args


def run_jobs(jobs, workers=1):
    q = Queue()
    def worker(idx):
        while True:
            args = q.get()
            run(idx, *args)
            q.task_done()

    for job in jobs:
        q.put(job)

    for i in range(0, workers):
        t = Thread(target=worker, args=[i])
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    q.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_jobs([('job', i) for i in range(0,10)], workers=5)
```

I didn't need to use multiprocessing (my workers are just for calling an external process), but this could be extended.  The API for multiprocessing changes it a touch, here's how you could adapt:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from Queue import Empty
import time
import random

def run(idx, *args):
    time.sleep(random.random() * i)
    print idx, ':', args


def run_jobs(jobs, workers=1):
    q = Queue()
    def worker(idx):
        try:
            while True:
                args = q.get(timeout=1)
                run(idx, *args)
        except Empty:
            return

    for job in jobs:
        q.put(job)

    processes = []
    for i in range(0, workers):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=[i])
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes: 
        p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_jobs([('job', i) for i in range(0,10)], workers=5)
```

Both versions will output something like:

```
0 : ('job', 0)
1 : ('job', 2)
1 : ('job', 6)
3 : ('job', 3)
0 : ('job', 5)
1 : ('job', 7)
2 : ('job', 1)
4 : ('job', 4)
3 : ('job', 8)
0 : ('job', 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it would work with `Pool`, but printing `Process` gives some unique output:

```
x = Process(target=time.sleep, args=[20])
x.start()
print(x)  # <Process name='Process-5' pid=97121 parent=95732 started>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to map to a class method by getting the function handle using `getattr`, then using a wrapper to pack and unpack as many arguments as I wanted to pass to the method being mapped. In my case I was passing methods from the same class where the pool was being launched, but you can also pass an object as well to map to different classes.

This is the code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool


def warp(args):
    func = args[0]
    frame = args[1]
    left_over = args[2:]
    func(frame, *left_over)


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_flag = 5

    def exec_method(self, method, int_list, *args):
        obj = getattr(self, method.__name__)

        packed = list()
        for i in int_list:
            pack = list()
            pack.append(obj)
            pack.append(i)
            for arg in args:
                pack.append(arg)
            packed.append(pack)

        print("Start")
        pool = Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        pool.map(warp, packed)
        print("End")

    def method1(self, my_str):
        print(self.my_flag, my_str)

    def method2(self, i, print_str, bool_flat):
        print(multiprocessing.current_process(), self.my_flag, i, print_str, str(bool_flat))


cls: MyClass = MyClass()
cls.my_flag = 58
cls.exec_method(cls.method2, [1, 5, 10, 20, 30], "this is a string", True)
```

This is the output:

```
Start
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)> 58 1 this is a string True
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)> 58 5 this is a string True
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-4, started daemon)> 58 20 this is a string True
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-5, started daemon)> 58 30 this is a string True
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)> 58 10 this is a string True
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that could be considered :

```
import multiprocessing
import math

def worker(worker_id, pid_dict, data_dict, worker_dict, res_dict, nb_worker):
    current = multiprocessing.current_process()
    pid_dict[worker_id] = current.pid
    worker_dict[worker_id] = worker_id 
    data_len = len(data_dict)
    chunk_size = math.ceil(data_len / nb_worker)
    start_index = worker_id * chunk_size
    end_index = min(((worker_id + 1) * chunk_size - 1), data_len)
    res_dict[worker_id] = 0
    
    for i in range(start_index, end_index):
        res_dict[worker_id] = res_dict[worker_id] + data_dict[i]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nb_worker = 7
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    pid_dict = manager.dict()
    worker_dict = manager.dict()
    data_dict = manager.dict()
    res_dict = manager.dict()
        
    for i in range(100000):
        data_dict[i] = i
    
    jobs = []
    
    for i in range(nb_worker):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (i, pid_dict, data_dict, worker_dict, res_dict, nb_worker))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
        
    print("Pid")
    print(pid_dict.values())
    print(" ")
    print("Worker id")
    print(worker_dict.values())
    print(" ")
    print("Sum data by worker")
    print(res_dict.values())
    print(" ")
```