# What is the difference between ident and pid of processes in Pythons `multiprocessing`?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Processes created and started with `multiprocessing.Process` have an attribute `pid` (the process id) and `ident`. Isn't `pid` also an identifier? What is the difference between those two?

The help isn't helping either:

```
 |  ident
 |      Return identifier (PID) of process or `None` if it has yet to start
 |  
 |  pid
 |      Return identifier (PID) of process or `None` if it has yet to start
```

### Example

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def whatever():
    print("child")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("child done")

created = multiprocessing.Process(target=whatever)
created.start()
time.sleep(1)
print("pid={}".format(created.pid))
print("ident={}".format(created.ident))
```

In my cases, `pid == ident`. Is that always the case? Is that probably OS specific? (I run it on Linux. What happens on Mac / Windows?)

Comment: same thing on windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190981/get-a-unique-id-for-worker-in-python-multiprocessing-pool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e1f688fe0f0a612e54c09f5a7027a834dd8b8d5/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L234-L245).

**cpython/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py:**

```
class BaseProcess(object):

    ...

    @property
    def ident(self):
        '''
        Return identifier (PID) of process or `None` if it has yet to start
        '''
        self._check_closed()
        if self is _current_process:
            return os.getpid()
        else:
            return self._popen and self._popen.pid

    pid = ident  # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    ...
```

Thus `multiprocessing.Process.pid` is just an alias for `multiprocessing.Process.ident`. Note that `multiprocessing.Process` provides the `ident` property so that it is compatible with `threading.Thread` API. According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process):

> In addition to the
> [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)
> API,
> [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process)
> objects also support the following attributes and methods:
>
> **pid** - Return the process ID. Before the process is spawned, this will be `None`.
>
> ...

Comment: What does `self._popen and self._popen.pid` do?

Comment: @MartinThoma It evaluates to `self._popen.pid` provided that `self._popen` is not `None` (otherwise the entire expression evaluates to `None`).

Comment: Why not directly `return self.pid`?

Comment: @MartinThoma `pid` is defined to be an alias to `ident`. Therefore `return self.pid` is the same as `return self.ident` which would result in infinite recursion if used inside the definition of `BaseProcess.ident`.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't see the last line `pid = ident`. Thank you for your answers :-)