# How to have dedicated variable for multiprocessing worker, which keeps its value between calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```
pool = Pool(cpu_count())
pool.imap(process_item, items, chunksize=100)
```

In the `process_item()` function I am using structures which are resource demanding to create, but it would be reusable. (but not concurrently shareable) Currently within each call of `process_item()` it creates the resource in a local variable repeatedly. It would be great performance benefit to create once (for each worker) then reuse

**Question**

How to have delegated `cpu_count()` instances for those resource, and how to implement the `process_item()` function to access the appropriate delegated instance belonging that particular worker?

Comment: You can use a factory function, but that would mean you will have to use multiprocess, a fork of multiprocessing, since factory functions aren't picklable by default in python

Comment: ?...I am already using multiprocessing, pool.imap forks multiple python processes...

Comment: one is multiprocess**ing** and the other one is multiprocess. They both are identical except for the fact that the one without the *ing* uses `dill`, which can pickle more things  in general. Are you okay with using libraries outside the builtins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use anything outside the standard library, I would suggest using using an `initializer` when creating the pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process
import os
import random

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.var = random.randint(0, 1000)

    def get(self):
        print(self.var, os.getpid())


def worker(some_arg):
    global expensive_var
    expensive_var.get()

def initializer(*args):
    global expensive_var
    expensive_var = A()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(8, initializer=initializer, initargs=())
    for result in pool.imap(worker, range(100)):
        continue
```

Create your local variables inside the `initializer`, and make them global. Then you can use them inside the function you are passing to the pool. This works because the `initializer` is executed in when each process of the pool starts. So making them `global` would make it a global variable *in the scope of the child process* only, allowing access to it during execution of the function you passed to the pool.

There was a stackoverflow answer that explained all this better, but I can't seem to find it for now. But this is basically the gist of it.

Comment: Perhaps this is the answer you're remembering? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42817946/2112722

Comment: @SarahMesser Not the one I was referring to, but it's close enough to offer some context.